# Excel OFFSET formula to get data from horizontal to vertical

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to reference data from Horizontal and output to vertical cell without space in between. May I know how should I use OFFSET formula to achieve the desire output in vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `=OFFSET($H$2,0,3*(ROW()-6))` in E6 and fill down to achieve the result shown in your image.

Comment: Thank you very much. It can achieve what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this ! Change the range() if you need !

```
Sub macro()

'Variable declaration
Dim tbl As Range
Dim col1 As Variant

col1 = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)
Set tbl = Range("A1:A4")

With tbl
    .Value = Application.Transpose(col1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I can leverage the algorithm for other purposes. :)